# update rsync in high sierra

Tags: high-sierra, rsync

I want to update rsync in high sierra.

After I installed it using homebrew, it is installed in

`/usr/local/Cellar/rsync/3.1.3_1`

`rsync --version` still shows 2.6.9. how can I fix that?

Comment: Truck.app is an rsync client for Mac that comes with rsync 3.1.1 bundled.  http://bonhardcomputing.com/truck/  (disclaimer: I am a developer)

Answer (score 4):

Try closing terminal window and opening it again. Rsync changes only take place after closing terminal session. Helped in my case.

Answer (score 2):

From [this article:](https://bayton.org/2018/07/how-to-update-rsync-on-mac-os-high-sierra/)

> Open the terminal and paste the command:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
> ```
>
> Homebrew will link most software to `/usr/local/bin`. However, the
>   terminal may be looking in other folders first, so lets make sure that
>   `/usr/local/bin` is the first line in our path list.
>
> ```
> sudo nano /private/etc/paths
> ```
>
> Now you are ready to install the new Rsync version, and can do so as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> brew install rsync
> ```
>
> Once completed, you should sign out and back in to MacOS.
>
> When entering the command below, you will see now that you are using
>   rsync 3.1.3 (at time of writing), instead of rsync 2.6.9. You are no
>   longer running a 12 year old version of Rsync!
>
> ```
> rsync --version
> rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31
> ```
>
> As simple as that.

Comment: Is there a way to have brew install rsync v3 under a different name (e.g. `rsync3`)? v2 and v3 have some different (incompatible) options, so a command that works fine with v2 may fail with v3 because the options mean something else. Thus, it'd be safer not to override the builtin v2.

Comment: Te OP has already installed via Homebrew so most of this is not useful and the useful bit is not usually needed.

Comment: I did all these steps but still showing the old version instead 2.6.9